# how hide list items filter html search box

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to hide list items from filter html search box.

e.g it show me items only when i click on search box then show me item list

otherwise hide list items in normal codition.

- Adele
- Agnes
- Billy
- Bob
- Calvin
- Christina
- Cindy
- kandy
- lakum
- kool
- moon
- noon

If any one can correct this please.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #myUL li a {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }

    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>My Phonebook</h2>

    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

    <ul id="myUL">
      <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

if any one can correct this please.

Answer (score 0):

You should be good to go now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";

var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        
        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 
    
    // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
    /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }*/
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first big thanks for help your correction is close to my question but still probblem it shows many words  when i just click search box , kindly resolve this that it will  show me ony that words list when i type word in search box

Comment: This hides the list entirely. So when you search it doesn't show possible matches.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply hide the UL el once DOM is ready and then display the list if input field is set on focus. Try this code below using jquery.

```
 $(function(){
  $('#myUL').hide();
  $('#myInput').on('focus',function(){
    $('#myUL').show();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to your "myUL":
-Add a class to each list item

```
<li class='people'>Adele</li>)
```

Then add a CSS component to hide the list by default

- .people { display: none;}

In javascript:
Change this section:

```
if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
{
    li[i].style.display = "";
} else {
    li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

To (if else reversed and filter ==""):

```
if (!(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)) && filter == "")
    {
    li[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey There I found one solution this all of those others aren't working I tried all of them.

Here's the solution:

1. Give a class="search-bar-items" (in html) to all of the lists
2. In CSS write this code below.

   .search-bar-items{
   display:none;
   }

[list with the class name search-bar-items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVL0Y.png)

[CSS property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IaFS.png)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.